# Apache nifi use case

Tags: etl, apache-nifi

I need to create data pipeline, here is the flow i need
1- call social media apis like : Facebook graph API, twitter, Youtube and other platforms,at certain intervals, ex : call twitter API every 30 mins and pull data for certain keywords

2- Extract the data for certain pages, then process this data, like making some calculations on engagement and reach, then calling AI models through APIs to get sentiment and intent for each post, comment

3- finally insert this result into elasticsearch

What I have right now is native java code that calls the APIs to get the data, then throw it into kafka queue, and consumers do the heavy work of processing and calling the AI models APIs, then finally insert into Elasticsearch

I'm looking for an open source ETL tool because what I have right now lacks monitoring and takes time to make changes.

I came across apache nifi and i think it will be a good solution but i need opinions on my use case, please note that I will still be using kafka in the middle

Answer (score 0):

NiFi has many integrations with external data sources. Some are purpose-built like `GetTwitter`, `ConsumeKafkaRecord`, `PutElasticsearchHttp`, etc. It also has more generic processors like `InvokeHttp` to connect to REST APIs such as Facebook and YouTube. There may be some configuration needed such as getting a Facebook cert or API token for a secure connection (see [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/add-Certificates-Facebook-to-apache-nifi/m-p/103804) and [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Accessing-Facebook-Page-Data-from-Apache-NiFi-1-2/ta-p/246915)).

I recommend subscribing to the users [mailing list](https://nifi.apache.org/mailing_lists.html), the community is highly active and very responsive to incoming questions.